# What is the meaning of "alone of"? Is it a stock phrase?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

What is the meaning of "alone" here, used with the preposition "of"?

> Alone of prejudices, anti-Zionism is sacrosanct.

The link to the article this sentence is taken from: 
http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/corbyn-may-say-hes-not-anti-semitic-but-associating-with-the-people-he-does-is-its-own-crime-10487318.html

Comment: I don't think it's a stock phrase. Just from this fragment, I'd think 'alone of prejudices' means 'of all the prejudices, anti-Zionism is the only one that is sacrosanct'. As to what the author actually means by this, you'd have to provide more context.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. I added the link to the article.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link. In context, it just seems to be a poetic way of saying what I said in my above comment.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a stock phrase.

In this quote, the phrase 'alone of prejudices' is a poetic way of expressing:

> Of all the prejudices, anti-Zionism is the only one that is sacrosanct.

Comment: How can someone say "anti-Zionism is sacrosanct unless he/she is crazy? I think you over-simplified the interpretation.

Comment: You can read the full context of the ideas expressed in the link in OP's post. I suspect any further discussion about the validity of the ideas in the article is outside the remit of this Stack Exchange.

Comment: That's what I exactly did. Corbyn is criticized for being anti-Semitic. But he can be considered as an "anti-Zionist" without prejudices attached to it. That's the whole context.